# Select text inside a div when user select feature has disabled?

Tags: html, css

Here I got an issue with disable user selection on the page 
on google chrome browser when user double click on the page

Screenshot for whole page selection which I need to remove

- http://screencast.com/t/3WzzZ2wCabQp

For this I am using this code:

```
#body
{
   -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

It's working fine .
But it has disabled all content,
I want to user will be able to select texts in side a div 
Is it posible any other way so please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it back to *auto* for the specific div:

```
#body {
   -webkit-user-select: none;
}

div.selectable {
  -webkit-user-select: auto;
}
```

In HTML use:

```
<div class="selectable">
  This will be selectable
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response its realy helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
#body
{
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.yourdivinbody(probably container) 
{
  -webkit-user-select: all;
}
```